# Why is my WOFF font larger than the TTF font?

Tags: fonts, icons, webfonts, woff

From my understanding ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Open_Font_Format)), a WOFF format is basically a compressed OTF/TTF font.

If that is really the case, then why is my WOFF font bigger than my TTF font as seen in the screenshot below.

[image: Font sizes]

The fonts were generated using the popular [Icomoon.io](http://icomoon.io) service.

Has anyone else noticed similar results in their fonts?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the woff file was built correctly according to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/) (which [doesn't allow for the compressed font tables to be larger](http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#conform-compressedlarger) than the original tables), the size increase can be attributed to the inclusion of [extended metadata](http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#Metadata) and/or [private data](http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#Private).

Comment: metadata: yes (see the spec, it's just XML/text). private data: not necessarily, unless it happens to be text. You will need a tool that can separate the woff into the component parts (font data, extended metadata, private data). http://code.typesupply.com/wiki/woffTools might help with that (Python)